# get value from another case from case statement

Tags: php, sql-server

I have two case which is addagreement and upload. How I want to return value $docid from case upload to case addagreement?Please help me. thanks

```
switch ($dowhat)
 {          
case "addagreement":
     $msgid = 30807; 
     $tenancyid = Common::getSeqNum(SEQ_TENANCYID);
$query = "begin transaction; ";
$query .= "insert into tenancy_suppdocs (tenancyid, docid, docsource )
values ($tenancyid, $docid, $docsource);";
     $query .= "commit;";               
Common::writeLog($modifyid, $moduleid, $pageid, 0, $query, CT_DB);        
$conn->Query($query); 
     $ok = "/itadmin/admin/agreementlisting.php";                   $param = $tenancyid; 
MessageBox::Info($msgid,$param,"",$ok);
Common::writeLog($modifyid, $moduleid, $pageid, $msgid, $tenancyid, CT_INFO);                       
//echo "1|".$msg;
exit(0); 

break;
case "upload":
//others source code
 $docid = Common::getSeqNum(SEQ_DOCID);
```

Answer (score 0):

if that is the case you need `$docid` in both cases, you might want to declare `$docid` before the switch

Answer (score 0):

your question has no sense.

Let try to figure out what exactly do you want to achieve?

Do you understand that `switch...case` is just another variant of `if...elseif`?

Your questions looks like you have:

```
if ($var == 1) {
 $direction = 'to_the_right';
} elseif ($var==2) {
 $direction = 'to_the_left';
}
```

and you ask us how to set direction to_the_left when `$var==1`.

So generally yes, there are many optins how to do that, but everybody confused WHY do you need that?

Something wrong with your logic flow here.

Comment: when I create new tenancy agreement (tenancyid) it will go to case addagreement, and if I want to upload document there are button to upload document where it will call agreement.js which is function uploadSupportingDocs() > case upload (docid). so need to return back $docid to case addagreement to  insert into tenancy_suppdocs (tenancyid, docid, docsource )
values ($tenancyid, $docid, $docsource);";